# How to get the value of the selected ion radio button after submission using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, radio-button

.html

```
<ion-radio-group 
    *ngFor="let option of data" 
    (ionChange)="checkValue($event)" 
    [value]="item">
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>{{option.optionA}}</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="Not"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>   
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>{{option.optionB}}</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start"  value="Some"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>{{option.optionC}}</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="Most"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>{{option.optionD}}</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="All"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
</ion-radio-group>

<div class="evalbtn">
    <button (click)="print(event)" class="nextbtn" (click)="evaluation2()">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

.ts

```
data: any[] = [
  {
    "optionA":"Not at All",
    "optionB":"For some of the Time",
    "optionC":"For most of the Time",
    "optionD":"For all of the Time",      
  }
];

//function to print what is inputed in the form that is declared above
checkValue(event) { 
    console.log(event.detail.value)
}
 
print(event) {
    console.log(this.checkValue(event))
}
```

Comment: it's angular material yea simple html ?

Comment: yes, but Im trying to create more questions with the same radio button options and its value, how can I get all the value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `[(ngModel)`] instead of `[value]` for `ion-radio-group`.

```
<ion-radio-group *ngFor="let option of data"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
    (ionChange)="checkValue($event)">
<!-- items -->
</ion-radio-group>
```

And add `selectedValue` to your component:

```
selectedValue: any;

print(event) {
    console.log('Selected value: ', this.selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. I tried having a lot more questions, with the same option and value but once I clicked one radio button the other set of radion btn on another radio groups will be clicked also. how can I get all those value ?

Comment: @yeel I suppose, you can add an answer model to your data (to `option` in `*ngFor`). Then you can use `[(ngModel)]="option.selectedValue"`

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand how to do this "you can add an answer model to your data (to option in *ngFor)", I'm still a beginner, can you please elaborate more. Thank you

Comment: @yeel `data: any[] = [{ selectedAnswer: '', "optionA":"Not at All", "optionB":"For some of the Time", "optionC":"For most of the Time", "optionD":"For all of the Time" }];`. In this case, each item of data will have its own `selectedAnswer`.

Comment: is this how it should be ?     <ion-radio-group 
    *ngFor="let option of data" 
    [(ngModel)]="option.selectedValue">

   <!--<ion-items-->
   <ion-content>
      <ion-radio-group 
    *ngFor="let option of data" 
    [(ngModel)]="option.selectedValue">
   <!--<ion-items-->

</ion-radio-group>
   </ion-content>
  
<div class="evalbtn">
    <button (click)="print(event)">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>

Comment: maybe I did it wrong cause its still the same

Comment: @yeel What the same? You have an array with answers. You have access to it via `this.data[index].selectedAnswer`.

Comment: I already add the selectedAnswer to data, and changed the ngModel to [(ngModel)]="option.selectedValue">. when I click one radio btn the other radion btn from the other redio group will also be selected.

Comment: @yeel you should have single `<ion-radio-group *ngFor="let option of data"></ion-radio-group` element

Comment: that's why thank you so much for your help.